# Error Updating SELF_ATTENDEES_STATUS in Events Table Google Calendar Android

Tags: android, android-studio, google-calendar-api, android-contentprovider, android-calendar

I'm trying to update the SELF_ATTENDEES_STATUS in the Events Table in this way :

```
    private void UpdateCalendarEntry(int position, boolean isAccepted) {
        ContentResolver cr = mContext.getContentResolver();
        Uri updateUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI, getEventId(mEvents.get(position).getTitle()));

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        if(isAccepted) {
            values.put(CalendarContract.Events.SELF_ATTENDEE_STATUS, CalendarContract.Attendees.ATTENDEE_STATUS_ACCEPTED);
        } else {
            values.put(CalendarContract.Events.SELF_ATTENDEE_STATUS, CalendarContract.Attendees.ATTENDEE_STATUS_DECLINED);
        }

        cr.update(updateUri, values, null, null);
    }
```

But infortunately i get this error stack

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Updating selfAttendeeStatus in Events table is not allowed.
    at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:165)
    at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:135)
    at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.update(ContentProviderNative.java:572)
    at android.content.ContentResolver.update(ContentResolver.java:1720)
    at com.jmjsolution.solarup.adapters.EventAdapter$EventViewHodler.UpdateCalendarEntry(EventAdapter.java:346)
    at com.jmjsolution.solarup.adapters.EventAdapter$EventViewHodler.access$600(EventAdapter.java:91)
    at com.jmjsolution.solarup.adapters.EventAdapter$EventViewHodler$2$1.onClick(EventAdapter.java:227)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6597)
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6574)
    at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:778)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25885)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Is someone knows how to update this field please ?
Thank you.

Comment: A more appropriated stackexchange sub is android.stackexchange.com